# Amazon S3 Cognito Sync

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have set up my Amazon S3 project without much problem. I can upload and download files fine. However, I have realised that I missed the following code snippet from the documentation. I dont know what it does. And I do not know where to put it (App delegate didfinishWithLaunchOptions?) Also, What to put in myDataSet, myValue, and myKeys. I was wondering if someone could please explain that to me.

```
let syncClient = AWSCognito.defaultCognito()

let dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset")
dataset.setString("myValue", forKey: "myKey")
dataset.synchronize().continueWithBlock {(task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    //Your handler code here
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code relates with [Cognito Sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) service. You use Cognito Sync to synchronize application specific user data across devices. One example to use Cognito Sync is when you have a gaming app and user has game state and preferences stored in an app. Now when a user uses your gaming app from multiple devices, you might want to synchronize game state across devices to enable user to continue the game where he previously left. You may use Cognito Sync in your application as it suits your business logic and requirements. Check out this [sample project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/3843449915f39e5dfc43c5e985a41e7f491f9a7f/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift/CognitoSyncDemo/CognitoDatasetListViewController.swift) for reference implementation.

Comment: I am putting this function in app delegateDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions along side where I initialise S3 AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider. What do I do with dataset, value and key? Can I leave it as "MyDataset", "MyValue", and "MyKey"?